# Como usar outros métodos HTTP em formulários HTML?

Tags: node.js, formulário, express.js, http-métodos

Estou usando Express.JS para fazer um CRUD em NodeJS.

Estava tentando fazer uso dos novos métodos HTTP, como por exemplo, o `put` , mas quando coloco no atributo `method` do formulário aparentemente não da certo.

O código do formulário:

```
[...]

<form action="/post/content" method="put">

[...]
```

Como faço isso dar certo?

Uma parte do código back-end:

```
app.put('/post/content', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A solução

O método `PUT` não existe nos [padrões do HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method). O `DELETE` também não.

É comum utilizar este *workaround*:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
  ...
</form>
```

Ou fazer um `XMLHttpRequest` com o `PUT` no JavaScript do client-side.

#### Por que não existem os métodos PUT e DELTE em formulários HTML?

Nos esboços do HTML5 foi considerado utilizar os métodos `PUT` e `DELETE` e até foram implementados no browser Firefox em sua versão *beta*.

[**Considerar o suporte do PUT e DELETE como `method` do `form`** foi discutido no W3C e foi fechado como "resolvido, porém não será corrigido"](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10671) pela seguinte razão (tradução e ênfase minha):

> PUT como um `method` do `form` não faz nenhum sentido. Você não iria querer um PUT no *payload* de um formulário. O DELETE só faz sentido quando não há *payload*, então não faz sentido em formulários também.

No dia em que escrevo isso, em 2018, formulários HTML só suportam GET e POST.

Comment: Beleza, mas como faço para tratar isso no back-end?

Comment: Não precisa mudar o back-end.

Comment: @lffg basta usar app.put como já esta fazendo, então quando enviar via XMLHttpRequest com PUT ele vai executar o que estiver em app.put, se tiver um app.post não será executado, o proprio Express já faz a separação disto pra ti. O `app.get` = `ajax.open('GET', 'foo', true)`, `app.post` = `ajax.open('POST', 'foo', true)`, `app.put` = `ajax.open('PUT', 'foo', true)` e `app.delete` = `ajax.open('DELETE', 'foo', true)`

Comment: Muito obrigado,